# Access 2007, VBA: Error with simple click to open a report

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

For some reason I'm getting an error on the first line. Everything is named correctly. I used the button creator wizard to open a report I wanted.

```
Private Sub cmdReport2013_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdReport2013_Click


    stDocName = "rptAnalyst_Comp_2013"


Exit_cmdReport2013_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdReport2013_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdReport2013_Click

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Compile Error: Variable Not Defined

**EDIT2:** This report is based off a query. Does that matter at all?

**EDIT3:**

```
Private Sub cmdReport2013_Click()
Dim stDocName As String

On Error GoTo Err_cmdReport2013_Click

    stDocName = "rptAnalyst_Comp_2013"
    DoCmd.OpenReport (stDocName, acViewNormal)


Exit_cmdReport2013_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdReport2013_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdReport2013_Click

End Sub
```

It's saying syntax error on the DoCmd.OperReport part.

**EDIT 4: Working code with syntax solved.**

```
Private Sub cmdReport2013_Click()
Dim stDocName As String

On Error GoTo Err_cmdReport2013_Click

    stDocName = "rptAnalyst_Comp_2013"
    DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewReport


Exit_cmdReport2013_Click:
    Exit Sub


Err_cmdReport2013_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdReport2013_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Dim stDocName as string?

Comment: Before the initialization.

Comment: Now it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I updated my answer, try that and let me know what you get.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub cmdReport2013_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdReport2013_Click

docmd.openReport "rptAnalyst_Comp_2013"


Exit_cmdReport2013_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_cmdReport2013_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_cmdReport2013_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything when I click on it. Not sure why. The names are correct. If I select a Macro instead of [Event Procedure] the Macro works.

Comment: Compile error:syntax error: docmd.open report "rptAnalyst_Comp_2013"

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between the words "open" and "report". It's DoCmd.OpenReport.

Comment: @SimonKingston , I fixed it, I was in a bit of a rush and accidentally hit space is all, good catch.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub cmdReport2013_Click()
Dim stDocName as String

On Error GoTo Err_cmdReport2013_Click

    stDocName = "rptAnalyst_Comp_2013"
    DoCmd.OpenReport (stDocName)


Exit_cmdReport2013_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdReport2013_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdReport2013_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Great you just made me print 16 pages.

Comment: But it worked.  It's up to you to make sure your report is only printing what you want.  ;o)

Comment: I don't want it to print. I want it to show up. It auto printed the 16 pages. Not something I wanted.

Comment: Ahhh!  Add acViewPreview after the report name.  DoCmd.OpenReport (stDocName, acViewPreview)

Comment: I don't want the preview either. I want to open the report. Access is being weird. I should be able to use a simple wizard for this. Something's wrong outside VBA.

Comment: Here's your options: acViewDesign or acViewNormal (default Prints the report immediately) or acViewPreview.  That's all that's allowed.  Whichever one you want, put it in the code instead of acViewPreview.

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis ( "()" ) from that line of code.  I don't think they're necessary.

Comment: If my code was helpful, please consider giving my answer a checkmark and/or upvote, if you don't mind.  Glad I could help!